# Can I add a youtube subscribe button to my flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, youtube, subscribe

I want to add a youtube subscribe button to my flutter app just like you do on web pages ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button ). Are there any methods for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own button. It should have a youtube subscribe link, which you get by using your channel's URL and adding `?sub_confirmation=1` at the end. If you want the subscriber count you can get it from [Youtube's API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels).

Comment: Oh yeah didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: When I added a button with subscribe url and launched with url_launcher. It"s not working

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: @Mahi did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: Nope.. I didn't checked after that. If you have any solution. Please mention here